# Anaconda error while opening prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Whenever I open Anaconda prompt, I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 170, in main
    import conda.cli.activate as activate
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\activate.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ..exceptions import (ArgumentError, CondaEnvironmentError, CondaSystemExit, CondaValueError,
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .common.url import maybe_unquote
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\url.py", line 8, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 177, in main
    from ..exceptions import handle_exception
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .common.url import maybe_unquote
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\url.py", line 8, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

It worked perfectly fine till a few days ago.

Also on cmd, when I type in the `conda` command, it displays:

```
C:\Users\souvi>conda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 181, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .common.url import maybe_unquote
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\url.py", line 8, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Users\souvi\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall your anaconda?